# Creating readable list output in PHP/Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, formatting

I'm trying to figure out how best to get this PHP statement

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT verb, display_name AS organization, inline_the FROM
userorganizations U, organizations O WHERE U.org_id = O.ID AND 
U.user_id=$author_id", OBJECT);
```

To spit out something like the following:

> John works for Initech, owns John's Tasty Pastry, **and** writes for the New York Times

I can do almost everything except figure out a good way to insert the bolded "and" up above: I don't know how to iterate through to just before the final row, do something special, then run the final row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `get_results()` returns a numerically indexed object of the results.  It's easy to figure out how many results you have by assigning that object to a variable and then using `count()` to figure out how many results you have.

So:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(..., OBJECT);

foreach($results as $result) {
    if($result == $results[count($results) - 1]) echo '<strong>and</strong>';
    ... The rest of your loop here ...
}
```